# Testing promises with Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js, q

I have a very simple promise and I want to test if it has been resolved or rejected based on the input the promise takes.

```
var isPair = function(number) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  if (number % 2 == 0) {
    deferred.resolve(number + " is pair.");
  } else {
    deferred.reject(number + " is not pair.");
  }
```

}

```
it("rejects the promise when number is not pair", function() {
  return expect(isPair(1)).to.be.rejected;
}
```

My test returns true even when I set the param to 2 for example.

Can you give me an example of how I test if a promise resolved or rejected? If possible with the expect syntax please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using chai, you can install [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/) to get the syntax you want:

```
it("rejects the promise when number is not pair", function() {
  return expect(isPair(1)).to.eventually.be.rejected();
});
```

Otherwise, you could use the `done()` callback supplied by mocha to indicate success/failure:

```
it("rejects the promise when number is not pair", function(done) {
  isPair(1).then(function() {
    done(new Error('Should have rejected'));
  },
  function() {
    done();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answer is solid, alternatively you can do:

```
it("rejects the promise when number is not pair", function() {
    return isPair(1).then(Promise.reject, Promise.resolve);
});
```

This basically "inverts" the promise and expects the promise to reject (resolving it if it does, and rejecting if it doesn't).

Since you're using Q and not native promises or a new library:

```
it("rejects the promise when number is not pair", function() {
    return isPair(1).then(Q.reject, Q);
});
```

You don't really need the expect syntax here :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for you reply. I really like the syntax of your second example, can you explain me please what the Q.reject and Q actually do? Thank you.

Comment: @west Q converts anything into a promise - even a rejected error so it recovers if there was an exception. Q.reject rejects whatever the promise was fulfilled with - so it's basically an "invert" - it turns fulfillments to rejections and vice versa.